# Access Application Context from class that doesn't extend Activity/Service

Tags: android

I handle login for my application in a class that extends application. The application then maintains an object of this class at all times. This means that I can access that specific object from any class that extends activity or service by calling

```
LoginModeller lm = ((LoginModeller)getApplicationContext());
```

However, I now need to access the object from a class that does not extend activity or service (It extends nothing). Is there some way to access the application context from a class like this, or I do have to re-factor my `LoginModeller` as a singleton or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who creates this object? In your constructor you can pass in a `Context` and store it as an instance variable:

```
private final Context context;

public MyObject(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using DI with [roboguice](http://roboguice.googlecode.com) but I am :)

From my point of view, the cleanest way to do this is using a `staticInjection`. [Here's how](http://jeffangelini.com/android/injecting-context-into-a-database-adapter-with-roboguice/).

Comment: This looks interesting, but I am too far into dev to make such a great change now